# npm run dev: [webpack-cli] Error: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Good day everyone! I'm building a Laravel app that runs on Version 8 with Laravel Mix and Vue. I'm almost done with my application and after running npm run dev, I've been outputted this main error

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
```

There is also another similar chunk of error regarding an invalid loader to process a Vue file

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/components/EditNode.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div class="panel panel-default">
|         <div class="panel-heading">Edit note</div>
```

I've been spending time rechecking code, but to no avail. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!